# mysql finding not exist records in mutiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, exists

```
    CREATE TABLE `Students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Students` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Student 1'), 
(2, 'Student 2'),
(3, 'Student 3');



CREATE TABLE `lessons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `lessons` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Lesson 1'),
(2, 'Lesson 2'),
(3, 'Lesson 3');



CREATE TABLE `completed` (
  `student` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lesson` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `completed` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `completed` (`student`, `lesson`, `completed`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(2, 1, 1);
```

we are adding students who completed lessons to "completed" table. we need to get 5 student with lesson which id not exists in "completed" table.

example output is;

```
1, 1
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
3, 1
3, 2
```

thank you

Comment: Looks to me like a job for `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

Following should show all of the students that don't have a completed lesson, which is what I think you're asking for:

```
SELECT Students.id, Students.name FROM Students LEFT JOIN completed
ON Students.id = completed.student WHERE completed.student IS NULL;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE completed.student IS NULL LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Fixed the joun condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT s.Id, s.Name
FROM Students s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Completed
    WHERE s.Id = student
)
```

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your code; 

FROM Students s?

SELECT 1 ?

Comment: @ÖnderErol Does it give you the result you want or not?

Comment: @ÖnderErol It grabs all students in `Student` that don't exist in `Completed`.

Comment: sorry, there is blank result.

Comment: @ÖnderErol Are all students exist in `Completed`?  What differentiate whether student completed or not?  `completed` column (1 or 0)?

Comment: no ... we ll insert record if / when student finished a lesson

Comment: @ÖnderErol Then it shouldn't give you blank result.  Are there records in `Students` table?  Try `SELECT * FROM Students`